# Google Analytics for IOS - Phonegap

Tags: ios, events, cordova, google-analytics

I have a requirement of adding the Google Analytics feature on Phonegap application, I had already created the same for Windows and Android and it's working fine but for iOS, I am not getting any success.

I have gone through some of the links i.e. https://github.com/phonegap-build/GAPlugin but still no success, would anyone suggest the complete documentation and process. I am using cordova 2.3.0.

I have tried using on native iOS application and it worked but my requirement is on Phonegap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above issue got resolved, thanks to this tutorial ----> **https://github.com/jelled/google-analytics-cordova-ios**